# How to slide button vertically in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

How to slide button vertically in iphone  by programmatically ?

Hey i have 7 images. and i want to display only 3 images vertically. and other images will be display when user scroll it upward.

Comment: What do you mean ? By touching them or programmatically ? Please describe in more detail what you want to accomplish, otherwise we won't be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at UIScrollView class :-) and then at UIImageView
If I understand what you want to do...

But we won't code you the thing ;-)

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

add scrollview and setPagingEnabled =yes;

then

two way

1.add all images in view as subview and set the frame of them by one by one

2.in one view while scroll up add next image in view and remove old image.

right.Got it?

Answer (score 0):

i think this tutorial will help you

http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/pagecontrol-example-in-iphone/